# how to tell the notification status of window phone MPNS

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

when send notification to window phone via mpns, it often response with http header "X-DeviceConnectionStatus=Inactive"! what happened in the window phone making mpns response like this? should i send the notification again?

Answer (score 0):

`Inactive` status is only mentioned briefly [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941100%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_TFDCS). They only state it as a possible status without specifing what it means.

> "X-DeviceConnectionStatus"":"1*DeviceConnectionStatusValue
>
> DeviceConnectionStatusValue = STRING
>
> (Connected|**InActive**|Disconnected|TempDisconnected) //For example:
>
> X-DeviceConnectionStatus:Connected

I read somewhere else that it means `The MPNS cannot determine if a device is off or has no internet connection.  It looks the same to the MPNS (the device cannot be contacted).` Therefore I would treat it the same as `Disconnected`, i.e., attempt to re-send the notifications, but not too often.